# Any listener for input type text

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Hi in my input type text I want to call URL if user enters suppose three characters how to do that
how to add listener? I am developing search application Now I am sending hard coded value "oil" in below code . Here is my code:

```
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>jQM Autocomplete</h1>

    </div>

    <div data-role="content">


        <p>
            <input type="text" id="searchField" placeholder="Categories">
            <ul id="suggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
        </p>

        <p>
            <a href="https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js" data-role="button">Download the code</a>
        </p>


    </div>

</div>

<script>

    $("#mainPage").bind("pageshow", function(e) {

        var substr,out,pra;

            var finalStr = "system"+encodeURIComponent("|^")+"0"+encodeURIComponent("|^")+"oil";
             var encodedURL = encodeURI("http://myDomainSearch.asp?requestString=");
             var parameters =  decodeURIComponent(finalStr);


        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        url: encodedURL,
        data: parameters
      }).done(function( msg )
              {
                  response  = msg
                    alert(response);
                    if(response.charAt(0)=='0')
                    {   
                        console.log("***"+ response);                                                         
                        substr = response.split('$');   

                        alert("inside if"+substr);

                        for (var out = 0;out<substr.length-1;out++)
                        {                       
                            pra = substr[out].split('|^');
                            console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>"+pra[0]);
                            console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>"+pra[1]);
                            console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>"+pra[2]);
                            console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>"+pra[3]);                  


                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("error")
                    }

                    $("#searchField").autocomplete({
                    target: $('#suggestions'),
                    source: pra,
                    link: 'target.html?term=',
                    minLength:1
                });
             }              
        );
    });
</script>
```

Now instead of hard coded value I want that if user enter three characters in input type text above then it hit URL and according to that response will be shown in list.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the keyup event and check the length of the text in the input

Comment: could make response simpler to work with by returning json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to give an example:

```
$('#searchField').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim( this.value );
  if(val.length == 3) {
    // do something
     .....
     ....
    var finalStr = "system"+encodeURIComponent("|^")+"0"+encodeURIComponent("|^")+ val;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.live` to listen to global keypress events

```
<form>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" id="txtHidden" style="display:none"/>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).live('keypress', function (e) {

$('#txtHidden').val($('#txtHidden').val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which));

    if($('#txtHidden').val() == "oil")
        alert("Black gold!");
});​
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/maSFE/)